# check selected radioButton from second activity

Tags: android

in first activity i have two radio button and button and i want when selected one of them and press button intent to second activity and and show self toast
my code is below and my app force close

first activity

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup2);
        int selection = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        if (selection==R.id.rb4) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MyActivity2.class);
            intent.putExtra("art","0") ;
            startActivity(intent);
        }
           else if (selection==R.id.rb5) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MyActivity2.class);
            i.putExtra("sport","1") ;
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
});
```

second activity

```
String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString("art");
String value2 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("sport");
if (value.equals("0")){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "this is my Toast message1)",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else if (value2.equals("1")){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "this is my Toast message2)",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: can you post your error log

Comment: 3-31 06:28:31.190: ERROR/PGA(520): PgaSocketWriteAllHdipc: hd_ipc_send() failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here

```
String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString("art");
String value2 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("sport");
```

You are sending only one value from the first activity

i.e either "art" will be sent or "sport" will be sent,while in your second activity you are fetching both values.So this will end up as a nullpointerexception everytime.

Comment: I am adding another answer wait

Comment: Check if the extra string exist before defining your values. Use the [Intent.hasExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#hasExtra%28java.lang.String%29) method to check if an extra value exists with the associated values.

Comment: @VarunMadhvani instead of adding another answer, you'd better edit **this** one.

Answer (score 0):

**Better solution is to use static variable**

in first activity declare, ***public static int num;***

if selection==R.id.rb4 than set num=1;

if (selection==R.id.rb5) than set num=2;

in second activity, if check>> first activity.num==1 than give toast1
first activity.num==2 give toast2

remove putextra as well as get extra...

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup2);
        int selection = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        if (selection==R.id.rb4){

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MyActivity2.class);
                intent.putExtra("art","0") ;
                startActivity(intent);
        }

           else if (selection==R.id.rb5){
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MyActivity2.class);
                i.putExtra("art","1") ;
                startActivity(i);


        }


    }
});
```

Second Activity

```
 String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString("art");
if (value.equals("0")){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "this is my Toast message1)",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else if (value.equals("1")){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "this is my Toast message2)",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: @chy I would still check if the extra exists before getting its value: if (getIntent().hasExtra("art")) { String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString("art"); }